# Android Studio + Liquid Fun

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, game-engine, liquidfun

I'm trying to setup Android Studio + [LiquidFun](https://github.com/google/liquidfun). I follow a lot of tutorials like these:

- http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/
- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview

But either isn't comprehensive or isn't work. I tried all, copy directly the files (C++) to my project, tried to import using NDK, tried to fix NDK with gradle, etc. But nothing works. I appreciate it too much if anyone could help me to solve my problem or to install Liquidfun properly.

Thanks.

Comment: A comprehensive answer and/or link to such answer is needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question detail. ? Did you follow the tutorial [here](https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html) for building ? If you are getting stuck at someplace providing the stacktrace or log would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following the instructions from here:
https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html

They seem clear enough. You need the NDK on your PATH for `ndk-build` to actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Java, you may want to try [JLiquidFun](https://github.com/mfaella/JLiquidFun), a derivative of LiquidFun with enriched Java bindings and pre-compiled native libraries.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

build .so, copy to AndroidStudio Project's lib dir

last year,i was compiled successfully, use Old version NDK and Android SDK.（This is very painful）

i think need It needs to be adapted to the new Android SDK

In particular, build statements in.mk files or.py files ， 
Because you're using the old version of the command line command